# Unnecessary tips in review audition

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

In reviewing, most of post properties are hidden (e.g. votes score) for reviewer will can't use it for his decision.

But sometimes I see different tips (direct and indirect) that are indicates post correctness

For example, answer accepted icon:
[image]

This screenshot was created after reviewing, but accepted icon was appeared before, when post was loaded for reviewing

Also sometimes I notice:

- That post creator's account is deleted
- Post comments indicating post correctness

I think that these items are unnecessary tips and using them is cheating

Comment: Congrats, you're paying attention.  Now think about all the folks who fail these.